# undefined method 'patch' - routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am beginner in Rails & MVC development, and need help with the below:

I am doing the example in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

In "5.12 Updating Posts", we are asked to add the following to our config/routes.rb:

```
patch "posts/:id" => "posts#update"
```

If I do that, and run `rake routes`, I am getting the below error:

```
undefined method `patch' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x390f078>
```

I get the same error when I go to - `http://localhost:3000/posts/1`

This is the line in edit.html.erb :

```
<%= form_for :post, url: { action: :update, id: @post.id }, method: :patch do |f| %>
```

I have Rails 3.2.1.

### Environment:

I am doing this in Windows 7. I installed Rails via railsinstaller.org. Browsers -  Chrome, Firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`patch` is only available in Rails `master` branch.

- Here is the related pull request: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/348
- Here is the blog article explaining the reasoning: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/25/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/
- Here is another great summary: http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/http-patch-verb-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Among other things, you need to point to the git repo in your `Gemfile` to use edge rails on an already-existing project.

```
gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
```

For now you should just use `PUT` instead of `PATCH`. Even when 4.0 comes out, `PUT` isn't going anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

fwiw, I backported the HTTP PATCH verb work for Rails 3.2 https://gist.github.com/bf4/8940203